# how can I split a dataframe by two columns and count number of rows based on group more efficient

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with more than 120000 rows, it looks like this

```
> head(mydf)
ID MONTH.YEAR VALUE
1 110  JAN. 2012  1000
2 111  JAN. 2012  1000
3 121  FEB. 2012  3000
4 131  FEB. 2012  3000
5 141  MAR. 2012  5000
6 142  MAR. 2012  4000
```

and  I want to split the data.frame depend on the `MONTH.YEAR` and `VALUE` column, and count the rows of each group, my expect answer should looks like this

```
MONTH.YEAR VALUE count
JAN. 2012  1000  2
FEB. 2012  3000  2
MAR. 2012  5000  1
MAR. 2012  4000  1
```

I tried to split it and use the `sapply` count the number of each group, and this is my code

```
sp <- split(mydf, list(mydf$MONTH.YEAR, mydf$VALUE), drop=TRUE);
result <- data.frame(yearandvalue = names(sapply(sp, nrow)), count = sapply(sp, nrow))
```

but I find the process is very slow. Is there a more efficient way to impliment this? thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
aggregate(ID~., mydf, length)
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
 mydf %>%
    group_by(MONTH.YEAR, VALUE) %>%
    summarise(count=n())
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, list(count=.N) , list(MONTH.YEAR, VALUE)]
```